# Дата в логах log4j

Tags: java, log4j

Сделал небольшое веб приложение. Написал к нему логгер log4j. В лог выводится нужная мне информация и датавремя когда и что произошло. 
  Дело в том что время, указанное в логах, берется, видимо, по какому то дефолтному часовому поясу. Как сделать так, чтобы выводило корректное время?  выражение вида

```
%d {HH:mm:ss}{GMT+3}
```

не помогло.

Comment: Время берется скорее всего с сервера.

Узнай какое время на серваке.

Ну а перед логингом поставь нужное или напиши

что-то вроде 

%d {HH+3:mm:ss}{GMT+3}

хех

Comment: все локально) использую томкат. на такую запись он выдает  
  04+3:31:24{GMT+3} хотя уже за полдень)))

Comment: Попробуй указать где-нить нужный тебе часовой пояс, я в JAVA не силен.

Comment: ну он тянет дефолтное время из JVM. соответственно мне нужно взять это время, обработать и передать при инициализации в логгер...И выяснить откуда у моей JVM вообще такое время...

Comment: Так а куда добавил? -Duser.timezone="Регион/город"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

видимо это баг у Sun. Timezone Updater Tool от Oracle даже не помогла.
Решил проблему так:

```
-Duser.timezone="Регион/город"
```

Эту строку нужно добавить в строку вызова приложения Java:

```
java -Duser.timezone="Регион/город" my.super.Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18765355/1828296
В частности, с таким форматом:

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSXXX}
```

Должно выводить корректные дату и время с указанием таймзоны.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/118553)

Comment: @iluxa1810 вроде бы я так и сделал: привел в качестве источника ссылку, но написал в посте, как нужно поправить конфиг log4j, чтобы дата и время выводились нормально. Если считаете некорретным мой ответ - исправьте его, а я приму правки, если они будут адекватными.